# addOnScrollListener not reached when Recycleview is reversed scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout

I have a Recycleview of videos and it has reversed scroll

`mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, VERTICAL, true));`

The first item in `recyclerview` is not seen by `addOnScrollListener`

```
addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
  @Override
  public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

    if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
      if (mediaCoverImage != null) {
        // show the old thumbnail
        mediaCoverImage.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
      }

      // There's a special case when the end of the list has been reached.
      // Need to handle that with this bit of logic
      if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
        playVideo(true);
      } else {
        playVideo(false);
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
  }
});
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: @Blundell first video in Recyclerview is not seen by onScrollListener so first video position is not working but in normal scrolling from top to bottom i'ts working normally hope that is clear

Comment: Do you add logs to the listener? I can't understand how the first item "is not seen by onScrollListener". How do you come to that conclusion?